# Show Results of Each Table as Row

Tags: mysql

I am currently building a prototype website that shows data. The data is being entered into 1 database using a cronjob. The cronjob submits random data to 3 tables in the 1 database. For the most part, I have figured out the majority of the queries I would like to use ([see website](https://azcs.d1g.it)). There is one more query that I just cant seem to wrap my head around. So each table is its own location and so far I am able to create totals for hourly, weekly, monthly, etc...

My issue is, I want to generate a comparison page to compare the resource usage between locations. So instead of the resources being the columns in the table from the query, I want the location name in the columns with a total from that location.

**Currently**

```
May 29, 2019 6:00pm | Water Total | Electric Total | N. Gas Total | Solar Total
```

**What I Want**

```
May 29, 2019 6:00pm | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3
```

The above example (What I Want) would only show one resource, like WATER TOTAL.

Here is a screenshot of my db structure.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not a DB administrator or expert by any means. Once I see it done I can surely manipulate it and make it do exactly what I need for different time frames.

Comment: You said you have 3 tables, but you only showed 1 table in the image. What's in the other 2 tables?

Comment: Is each location in its own table? That's not generally a good design. Dynamic data should be in table contents, not table or column names.

Comment: Ah, yes. The 3 tables are wpdatable_23_1, wpdatable_23_1_1, wpdatable_23_1_2

Comment: Why do you have separate columns for year, month, day, hour when these are all included in the timestamp?

Comment: I pulled the data from a different website to learn. This is just a prototype for a potential customer so i am not too worried about how the data is structured in the backend at the moment. If they decide they like it and want to move forward, then ill make it pretty in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Join the 3 tables:

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.water as location1, t2.water as location2, t3.water AS location3
FROM wpdatable_23_1 AS t1
JOIN wpdatable_23_1_1 AS t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
JOIN wpdatable_23_1_2 AS t3 ON t1.timestamp = t3.timestamp
```

Make sure you have an index on this column:

```
ALTER TABLE wpdatable_23_1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (timestamp);
ALTER TABLE wpdatable_23_1_1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (timestamp);
ALTER TABLE wpdatable_23_1_2 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (timestamp);
```

Comment: B-E-A-UTIFUL! You're the best!

Comment: One issue. It is taking about 30 seconds for the query to finish. It does finish, just takes forever. The queries I have built, the basic one, take about 1-2 seconds to render data.

Comment: Add an index on the `timestamp` column in all the tables.

Comment: LOL...thats a new one for me. Like I said I am no DB admin. Got something that can educate me? I know google is full of stuff, but figured I'd ask :)

Comment: Updated the answer. But if you're going to run a database, you need to learn this stuff, you can't expect to get by asking on the Internet for every little thing.

Comment: I found how to change it. Very simple task. Just a couple of mouse clicks in phpMyAdmin. Like I said, I am learning. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Making a `UNIQUE` index on a `TIMESTAMP` is risky -- can't there by two things that happen in the same second?  How about just a plain `INDEX`.

Comment: @RickJames From his data, it looks like these are periodic meter readings, so there shouldn't be multiple at the same time. The JOIN won't work properly if there are duplicates, you'll get multiple pairs.